# Using SwiftUI with @AppStorage and on-the-fly function call

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, view

I am trying to use `@AppStorage` to read/save a value and calculate something with it, but I am failing to call a function within my `ContentView`. Example:

**Helper.swift**

```swift
func powerized(x: Decimal) -> Decimal {
    let powerized: Decimal  = pow(x, 3) * 6.25
    return powerized
}
```

**ContentView.swift**

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  @AppStorage(StorageKeys.sourcePower.rawValue) var sourcePower = 15

  var body: some View {
     VStack {
         Text(powerized(x: sourcePower))
     }
   }
}
```

With this implementation, I get `Initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'Decimal' conform to 'StringProtocol'`.

If I put  a

```swift
var myValue: Decimal = powerized(x: sourcePower)
Text(myValue)
```

I get a conversion error `Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'Decimal'`. This probably is because of the variable not defined as `Decimal` but even making that change I then get
`Cannot use instance member 'age' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available`.

I am getting quite mad with this. Is there any change to make it working without creating a new class with `ObservableObject` ? The `AppStorage` already solves for updating the UI every time it changes.
I think, as a workaround, in theory I can precalculate what I want with my function as store it as well as the source value, but it does not make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has nothing to do with `@AppStorage`. Your `powerized` function returns a decimal, and you are trying to use is in a `Text()`. `Text()` requires a `String`. You can do:

```
  var body: some View {
     VStack {
         // Use .description which returns a String
         Text(powerized(x: sourcePower).description)
     }
   }
```

Either of those will make it a `String`.

Comment: The first approach fails. It keeps complaining `Instance method 'appendInterpolation' requires that 'Decimal' conform to '_FormatSpecifiable'`. The second works instead.

Answer (score 1):

Because decimals are formatted differently in different countries (e.g. some use comma as a decimal point) you have to use a formatter and there is a new convenience API for that:

```
Text(powerized(x: sourcePower), format: .number)
```

This way the label will also update automatically if the region settings change.